# Having trouble finding where a coordinate and a line touch (p5.js)

Tags: p5.js

I am working in p5.js (p5) and I am having trouble finding out if a line touches a constantly changing coordinate. I have looked over numerous different topics and posts on many different websites, including this one, but I either didn't understand exactly how to implement it, how it worked, or it wasn't the right topic. I have a set of coordinates that make up a line in an array, and I have a x and y variable that I need to find if touches the line. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set of coordinates for a line and another point determine if that point is on the line.

1. Transform the coordinates for the line into the equation y = mx + b
2. Plug the x, y of the given point into the equation and see if the equality holds to within some tolerance.

Example:

```js
 var line1 = [{x:25, y:10},{x:225, y:50}];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  line(line1[0].x, line1[0].y, line1[1].x,line1[1].y);
  var p = {};
  p.x = mouseX;
  p.y = mouseY;

  ellipse(p.x, p.y, 2, 2);
 
  console.log(p.x + " " + p.y);
  var tolerance = 0.5;
   
    // find the slope of the line and store it in variable m
    // by finding the difference in y values (rise) and dividing by the difference in x values (run)
    var m = (line1[0].y - line1[1].y)/(line1[0].x - line1[1].x);
    
    // find the line's y intercept, the point at which the line crosses the y axis
    // b = y - mx
    var b = line1[0].y - (m * line1[0].x);

    // now determine how close the given point is to falling on the line
    var y = m * p.x + b;
    var delta = Math.abs(y - p.y);
    console.log("delta: " + delta);
    if (delta < tolerance){
      console.log("The point is on the line");
    }  else {
      console.log("The point is not on the line");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you Charlie Wallace you are a life saver, I was about to give up on this and use a series of blocks with my project.